# How to give a name to a collection (generated automatically when we map many to many relationship)?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, relational-database, relationship

I am new to Sails js. I was trying for Customer and Account relationship(Many to Many).
I am able to create relationship between them. The joined collection which gets created when I insert first record, takes 'modelname1_attributename_ modelname2_attributename.

Can we give custom name to it as it will be easy to work with it further?.

I come from JAVA and Hibernate background and there is annotation in Hibernate which does the task I want.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change name of the automatically-generated "through" table used for Sails many-to-many associations.  However, you can specify the "through" table *manually*, instead of using the automatically-generated one, and then name it anything you want.  From the [Sails.js docs on through associations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations):

> Many-to-Many through associations behave the same way as many-to-many associations with the exception of the join table being automatically created for you. In a Many-To-Many through assocation you define a model containing two fields that correspond to the two models you will be joining together. When defining an association you will add the through key to show that the model should be used rather than the automatic join table.

So in your case you'd create a new model, e.g. `api/models/CustomerAccount.js`, like:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    customer:{
      model:'customer'
    },
    account: {
      model: 'account'
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the `Customer.js` and `Account.js` model files, use the `through` property when defining the association attributes, e.g. in `Customer`:

```
accounts: {
  collection: 'customer',
  via: 'customers',
  through: 'customeraccount'
}
```

As @zabware notes in his answer, you can use `tableName` to further customize the name of this table.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I really appreciate it! There is a slight mistake though: your second code snippet should be singular, so instead of `accounts: {...}` it should be `account: {...}`, or alternatively needs to be plural (though I prefer the singular approach, so each table row has a "customer" and an "account" instead of "customers" and "accounts".